# How can I connect my pressure source to my tire model?

Tags: simulink, simscape

I am working on Simulink with the Vehicle Dynamics Blockset. 
I'd like to connect a pressure source to my tire Break Pressure input with 2.0000.000 Pa which is 2 bars.

[image: Here's my model]

Sadly I don't know why it doesn't allow me to connect my hydraulic source... I can't convert it to a physical signal either. I'm very new so sorry if it sounds trivial.

Thanks !

Comment: 2 bar is 200 000 Pa...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your Longitudinal Wheel subsystem takes the pressure value as a Simulink signal in the BrkPrs input. Hence you don't need to add a hydraulic network, you can directly connect the 100000 constant4 block to the BrPrs input.

If you wanted to model the dynamics of a hydraulic circuit coupling with the wheel, you need to go under the mask of the wheel (click arrow in the bottom-left corner) and modify it. I cannot help you further without knowing what is underneath.